# RailsのDeviceを用いてログインしたユーザのログイン持続時間を増やしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Railsでwebサービスの開発を行っているものです。

現在ユーザの管理全般にはDeviceを使用しているのですが、
ユーザがログインした後、あまり時間が立たないうちユーザがログアウト状態になってしまいます。

Deviseでログインしたユーザのログイン持続時間を伸ばすのに良い方法はないでしょうか。
また、omniauthでfacebookログインも対応しているのですが、そちらも同じようにログイン持続時間を伸ばしたいと思っています。

同じような経験があるかたなどいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: DeviceではなくてDeviseでした。
申し訳ございません。

Comment: 検索すると出てくるものもありますので、確認済みの項目がある場合、記載されると良いと思います。

[Rails - Deviseでセッションのタイムアウトまでの時間を延ばす方法 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/kami30k/items/50d64c8a42e6798bc142)